# jQuery - Updating Select Fields After Form Reset

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to reset my HTML form with jQuery after a select field has been changed.

My problem is that, while the selected option seems to be resetting (I can click into the select field and the original value is now checked), the front-end select display isn't changing at all.

Here is the the HTML which sets the value of the select field on page load.

```
 <form class="form" id="product-details-form">
      <select class="form-control" id="supplier" name="productsupplier" disabled>
           <?php foreach($allSuppliers as $supplier) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $supplier['supplier_id']; ?>" <?php if ($productResult['product_supplier'] == $supplier['supplier_id']) { ?>selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $supplier['supplier_name']; ?></option>
           <?php } ?>
      </select>
 </form>

 <a href="javascript:;" id="product-vitals-edit"><i class="la la-edit"></i></a>
 <button id="product-details-footer-cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Clicking the Edit button unlocked the select field:

```
$("#product-vitals-edit").click(function(){

    $("#product-details-form :input").prop("disabled", false);

});
```

And clicking cancel resets the form and goes back to disabled.

```
$("#product-details-footer-cancel").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#product-details-form').trigger("reset");
    $("#supplier").trigger("change");
    $("#product-details-form :input").prop("disabled", true);

});
```

Again. The original value of #supplier IS being 'selected' on reset, but it doesn't show that on the front end.

Comment: Can you provide some more information like the html code?

Comment: We need Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Claudio I have updated the question with more details

Comment: @turivishal I don't want to reset to the first option. I want to reset to the value that was selected when the page loaded.

Comment: @AdamG - I think the crux of the issue (if I am deciphering your question correctly) is that you want to reset it **to what it was when the page loaded**. In order to do that, you must 1) store the value on page load and 2) reset it to that value later.

Comment: I have edited the question again to attempt to provide more clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
$("#supplier")[0].selectedIndex = $("#supplier")[0].selectedIndex;
```

Keep it just after your reset code

```
 $('#product-details-form').trigger("reset");
```

Comment: @AdamG
You want to reset back to the item that was selected when page was loaded, right?
Try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This code have no issue, check your select option, whether it have more than one selected attribute.

```js
$("#product-vitals-edit").click(function(){

    $("#product-details-form :input").prop("disabled", false);

});
$("#product-details-footer-cancel").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#product-details-form').trigger("reset");
    $("#supplier").trigger("change");
    $("#product-details-form :input").prop("disabled", true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="product-details-form">
      <select class="form-control" id="supplier" name="productsupplier" disabled>
      <option value="">None</option>
         <option value=“0”>Supplier 1</option>
         <option value=“1” selected>Supplier 2</option>
         <option value=“2”>Supplier 3</option>
         <option value=“3”>Supplier 4</option>
     </select>
     <a href="javascript:;" id="product-vitals-edit">Edit</a>
 <button id="product-details-footer-cancel">Cancel</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset using `$(selector).get(0).reset()`, your example html is working in snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#resetButton").on("click", function(){
      $("#product-details-form").get(0).reset()
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="product-details-form">
      <select class="form-control" id="supplier" name="productsupplier">
         <option value=“0”>Supplier 1</option>
         <option value=“1”>Supplier 2</option>
         <option value=“2”>Supplier 3</option>
         <option value=“3”>Supplier 4</option>
     </select>
 </form>
 <button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
```